# Looking for Landsat imagery from 1986 for Paraguay

Tags: qgis, landsat, landsat-5, forest-ecology

I have accessed many websites such as USGS, NASA, Earth explorer. Somehow none of them has access to the image in the location I need or when I use the USGS website I get a warning that says:

> The provided maps are not for purchase or for download; they are to be used as a guide for reference and search purposes only; they are not owned or managed by the USGS.

Does anyone have advice on where I can access good Landsat imagery for a land cover change analysis?

Comment: May be you can visit this website and download landsat data. https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, Please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. We are a *problem-solving* site. Data requests are off-topic here. Normally [opendata.se] would be a better resource, but it's possible that the data doesn't exist.

Comment: The warning you're getting is for the overlay maps, not the maps you can download. Make sure you have an account, and you should be able to get to the downloadable maps

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend signing up for Google Earth Engine and accessing the [Landsat 5 image collection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LT05_C02_T1_L2). Here's a quick bit of code I wrote for you including a cloud mask.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f5ab0240057b47bb7debcc1ddf2b5b8e

You should be able to run that in short order, but to do anything more there will be a learning curve for you. Nonetheless, it looks like there are ~15 cloud-free images in some parts of the country for 1986. Hopefully this can get you underway for your land change analysis.